# How can we multi-select and delete multi rows on a data grid view by Code?

Tags: c#, datagridview

here's my codes(it's simple Phone book and this is delete part of it)

```
      private void btnDeleteFromGV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PLS Enter a Row");
        }  
    }
```

I want to select two or more rows at the same time in a data grid view and be able to delete them

what should i do!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get initially selected rows to array and then remove them from gridview. Try with this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedRows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows
            .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(row => !row.IsNewRow)
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var row in selectedRows)
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);

        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
}
```

Selected rows before delete:
[image]

After button press:
[image]

Comment: This will delete all rows because when the last selected row was deleted, next one is selected automatically.

Comment: @msmolcic it wont delete the selected rows that I HAVE selected

Comment: @MostafaBouzari Not sure what you mean by that. It will delete all rows that are highlighted, isn't it what you want to do?

Comment: You must have `RowHeadersVisible=true` and select the rows only by clicking on RowHeaders, then it will be deleted. Otherwise you need to use `FullRowSelect` mode if you have `RowHeadersVisible=false`

Comment: @agasi that's exactly what i want to do

Comment: thaks for the pictures

Comment: this run time error happens when i try to delete 3 rows it's fine for 2 rows (Row index provided is out of range.\r\nParameter name: index"})

Comment: @MostafaBouzari I changed the code a bit, try it out now.

Comment: @MostafaBouzari can you post your code inside your question please?

Comment: what do you mean ?? inside of my question is exactly you're code

Comment: @MostafaBouzari it should work for unlimited amount of rows then.. something must be different :)

Comment: @AgasiMkhitaryan this line (   dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(index);)  because ({"Row index provided is out of range.\r\nParameter name: index"})

Comment: @MostafaBouzari But I changed the code after you said that, did you change it as well? I don't have such line in code anymore..

Comment: it worked thank you  but i will notify you if it had any more problem

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I couldn't fully understand what was needed, but i will leave this here maybe somebody will find it usefull.  
 
1) To delete rows in `DataGridView` with properties: `RowHeaderVisible=true`, `SelectionMode=RowHeaderSelect`,`Multiselect=true` *by* **selecting with mouse** and pressing the button, you may use this code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedCount = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;
        while (selectedCount > 0)
        {
            if (!dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].IsNewRow)
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
            selectedCount--;
        }
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection(); // to cancel auto-selection after the deleting
    }
}
```

You must select a row by **clicking on any RowHeader**  
  
2) To delete rows in `DataGridView` with properties: `RowHeaderVisible=false`, `Multiselect=true` *by* **selecting with mouse** and pressing the button, you need to set **`SelectionMode=FullRowSelect`**. Code will be **the same as 1)**.  
3) To delete rows in `DataGridView` with properties: `RowHeaderVisible=false/true`, `SelectionMode=FullRowSelect/RowHeaderSelect`, `Multiselect=true` *by* **code** based on special **condition** after pressing the button, you may use this code::

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)    // loop's start to check condition
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) == -1) // example of condition
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        int selectedCount = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;
        while (selectedCount > 0)
        {
            if (!dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].IsNewRow)
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
            selectedCount--;
        }
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
```

4) To delete rows in `DataGridView` *by* **selecting** a **cell** or **cells**  you may use this code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            if (oneCell.Selected)
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5577802/agasi-mkhitaryan it works but it has 2 problems first : i have to write codes for each condition in a if statement IF(selected.rows(0) or (1) or (2)  or .....) Second one is that my exception rises in this situation @agasi

Comment: @MostafaBouzari Would you please explain in details what are the problems and what effect you want to achieve?

Comment: @MostafaBouzari Ok. The question was how to multi-select `DataGridView` by code. I think I asnwered that question. If you want my code to fit your needs I need to undertand the hole task. Can you add some more info or create a new question more correctly and close this one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5577802/agasi-mkhitaryan i just also need to know how can i delete more than one row in one action @agasi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5577802/agasi-mkhitaryan it always deletes 3 rows @agasi

Comment: this will delete the first 3 rows too

Comment: @MostafaBouzari it will delete first 3 rows if you keep rows[0], rows[1], rows[2].Selected = true; He just gave you an example, your question is kinda unclear if none of these answers suits your needs..

Comment: @MostafaBouzari This code deletes any selected rows, If you select rows 4,3,2 then it will delete the last three rows (for 5x5 datagridview). I don't quite understand the problem, please, try to be more concrete about what is needed.

Comment: @AgasiMkhitaryan that's the problem it won't do what you're thinking,if i select rows 6 and 5 it will delete the  first and second and the third this is what happens   always

Comment: @MostafaBouzari You're confusing me, check out my whole class and picture example..

Answer (score 0):

```
            using (var context = new DB())
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgShow.SelectedRows)
                {
                    string id = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    int x = Convert.ToInt16(id);
                    var del = context.ServicesPrice.Where(current => current.Id == x).FirstOrDefault();
                    context.ServicesPrice.Remove(del);
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
```

you can write instead of cells[4]: columns Id in your DB.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is best to include explanations and references with your answer, not simply a block of code.